# C# - remove whitespace from input number to have int

Tags: c#, whitespace

How to remove white space from inside of input number:

1 987 to 1987 - I need input number to be int for the rest of script:

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32(args.Content);
            if (n >= 1000) 
                n = (int) (n - (n * 0.75));
```

Comment: Replace space with empty string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Replace(...):

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32(args.Content.Replace(" ",""));
if (n >= 1000) 
n = (int) (n - (n * 0.75));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string numberWithoutSpaces = new Regex(@"\s").Replace("12 34 56", "");
int n = Convert.ToInt32(numberWithoutSpaces);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32(args.Content.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution.

```
string str = new string(args.Where(c => c != ' ').ToArray());
int n = Convert.ToInt32(str);
```