# "Input string was not in a correct format" when converting to an int

Tags: c#

I can not for the life of me figure out why an error keeps throwing when I have other programs that look basically identical that don't throw this error. Any ideas?

```
sum = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxAdd1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBoxAdd2.Text)
```

Throws the error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Sorry. Here's the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int sum;
    int sub;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sum = 0;
        sub = 0;
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBlock.Text = "HELLO " + textBox.Text;
    }

    private void buttonadd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sum = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxAdd1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBoxAdd2.Text);
        textBlockadddisplay.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
    }

    private void buttonsub_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sub = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxsub1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBoxsub2.Text);
        textBlocksubdisplay.Text = Convert.ToString(sub);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use Int32.TryParse to verify you have convertible values.  Always post code next time, not images of code.

Comment: put a break point on that line and ceck what's the value of textBoxAdd2

Comment: The error is telling you that the string is not formatted properly - in other words, it can't be parsed to an int.

Comment: post real code not a screen shot @Audie

Comment: what are the values in the text boxes?

Comment: the OP will need to read the following and understand what it takes as an input and what it's `out` return type is [Int32.TryParse Method - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a number answers as to why this issue is occurring.
Here's some things you could think about:

1) What values are in textBoxAdd1 and textBoxAdd2?
You could be running into an issue where the number is too big to fit in an Int32 and you may need a larger datatype?

2) Have you tried debugging through your code and putting a breakpoint on that particular line? Then you will see exactly what is being passed in and maybe there's some formatting issue with the input - maybe you might need to strip some whitespaces?

If this is the issue, you can check this post:
[C# - remove whitespace from input number to have int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809866/c-sharp-remove-whitespace-from-input-number-to-have-int)

Comment: It was the whitespace issue.

Comment: A few of the kids I'm teaching VERY BASIC c# to were having this issue. They apparently used the space bar instead of the delete key to delete the Text Box default text that was in there. Thanks!

Comment: Ah I see, glad we figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

One of your text boxes is probably a value that cannot be converted to an int. One solution would be to check them using the in.TryParse Method first

```
int num1, num2;
if (int.TryParse(textBoxAdd1.Text, out num1) && int.TryParse(textBoxAdd2.Text, out num2))
{
    // They were assigned.
}
```